# Accessing Channel Entries in Module

Tags: channel-entries, playa, module

Ok so here's my idea. I have a site, and for example it's going to have multiple channels with relational data... So like a Cars channel and a features channel. The features will be tied to the cars with Playa. Now I'd like to create a Module that will interpret this data and do stuff with it but for sake of ease is it possible to easily grab the car data including all of it's features in a php object.

I know I could join everything but I was thinking there might be an easier way? Basically the the more detailed version of this is that I will be using the data to generate forms and make calculations in PHP so simply dropping them into a template won't work. I need to somehow access the data as a PHP object. I'd love to be able to drop the entry ID and pull all the data into an array or object...

Let me know if this is possible without manually Joining every field. Thanks!